# HC-06 bluetooth module working as slave device

Tags: bluetooth

When we say that the HC-06 is a slave bluetooth device it means that this device is connected to a Master bluetooth device. But i am a little confused regarding to the data transfer between Master and Slave since there is also HC-05 which is used as a Master or Slave. Does this have anything to do with data transfer or is this irrelevant?

For example a master (laptop's bluetooth) can send data to the slave device (HC-06) so as a uController connected with the HC-06 can use the received data **but** can the slave device send data **back** to the master device? For example if i want to measure some analog voltage from the ADC of a uController and send this value back to the master (laptop) through the HC-06 module, can i do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Master doesn't mean "the only one that talks". Slave can also transmit some data. Master in case of Bluetooth, in simple words, means "the one who initiates and closes the communication down".

Comment: When you say  Slave can also transmit ""some"" data i assume that you mean : slave can transmit data . So it is something like the I2C protocol where the Master Initiates and closes the transmission with the slave and also commands the slave what to do next meaning, to receive from or transmit data back to the Master. Correct?

Comment: Correct. Again in very simple words, Bluetooth is just a wireless serial protocol.